# How to sort line of char that every letter in line would be diffrent?

Tags: c++, sorting

I have 11 letters:
B D A A R A R B K A A
I need to sort them in that way that every next letter would be different than previous for example:
B D A R A R A B A K A
I tried doing this way:

```
bool sort = true;
while (sort)
{
    sort= false;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n-1; i++)
    {
        if (letter[i] == letter[i + 1])
        {
            swap(letter[i], letter[i + 2]);
            sort = true;
        }
    }
}
```

But program breaks. I don't know what to do. Can anybody help?
I'm still beginner, so I don't know any advance algorithms

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: Have you tried a simple greedy algorithm with backtracking?

Comment: For a better Stack Overflow experience, attempt to solve the problem yourself and ask questions, if needed, about the attempt.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one possible algorithm:

Input: `BDAARARBKAA`

First, group the letters and sort by count:

```
A 5
B 2
R 2
D 1
K 1
```

Make sure that the highest count is not greater than `int((N+1)/2)`

Fill in the slots starting with the biggest group and leave an empty slot between the equal letters, like this:

```
A.A.A.A.AB.
```

Then fill with the rest of the letters:

```
A.A.A.A.AB.
 B R R D  K
```

Result:

```
ABARARADABK
```

Answer (score 0):

I know that it will be impractical for long strings, but anyway, I will show the brute force approach.

Simply go through all permutations af the string and if there is no adjacent equal element, show this as one possible result.

If you would comment out std::sort, then you will get your expected solution. But for other test cases it may not work.

I will think more about the problem and maybe com up with a better algorithm . . .

Please see:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

#define InputFromUser 0

int main() {
#if InputFromUser
    // Ask the user to enter a string (a line of char)
    std::cout << "Please enter a string:\n";

    // Get a line from the user
    if (std::string line{}; std::getline(std::cin, line) && !line.empty()) {
#else
    // A test input string
    std::string line{ "BDAARARBKAA" };
#endif
    // Sort all letters in string
//  std::sort(line.begin(), line.end());
    // Go through all permutations
    do {
        // Check, if we have 2 consecutive equal characters
        if (std::adjacent_find(line.begin(), line.end()) == line.end()) {
            // If not, then show a result
            std::cout << line << "\n";
            // Stop searching. If you remove this statement, then you will get all solutions 
            // But all solutions might be astronomically long
            break;
        }
    } while (std::next_permutation(line.begin(), line.end()));

#if InputFromUser
    }
#endif
return 0;
}
```